# Expected 3 arguments but found 1

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am new in android programming. I am trying to create a store details activity. I have currently working user logging display Cloud Firestore data/add into the fire store data features. As the next part, I want to be able to update the data in the cloud firestone from the application. Right now I am trying to pull the single data into a single activity. I have come a cross with this error and I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks
My list activities class setUpRecyclerView function;

```
 Query query = todoRef.whereEqualTo("email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ToDoItem>().setQuery(query,ToDoItem.class).build();


       adapter = new ToDoAdapter(options);
```

I get this error in this function:

> 

```
  adapter = new ToDoAdapter(options);
                 ^
  required: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem>,Context,List<ToDoItem>
  found: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I get this error when I add this code in to my Adaptor class ProductsAdaptor function

```
public ToDoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem> options
            ,Context mCtx, List<ToDoItem> productList) {
        super(options);
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
```

When I take out the `List<Product> productList` codes from this function application works fine.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the constructor with the arguments that the error is asking you to provide? If you're getting this error ```ToDoAdapter``` must not not have a constructor that takes one ```FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ToDoItem>``` argument.

Comment: No I havent as I said I am new at andorid programming. Can you please post the code here?

Comment: Also I have updated my code I post the wrong function

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Please show us the content of your `ToDoAdapter`. Please respond also with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a constructor to work properly it needs to be supplied with the right type and amount of arguments. This constructor takes 3 arguments. You have supplied it only one. Create the other two it is expecting ( a `Context` object, and a `List<TodoItem>` object) and add them to the arguments you provide when constructing the `ToDoAdapter`. More specifically here in the code:

```
adapter = new ToDoAdapter(options, missingArgument1GoesHere, missingArgument2GoesHere);
```

Comment: The missing arguments are 
Context mCtx
 List<ToDoItem> productList

When I write them like this it doesn't work How can I fit them in there ?

Comment: It may be helpful to take a step back and look into learning what constructors are in java and how they are used. This is not an Android specific question but a basic programming concept. Understanding constructors will show you what is going on here.